# What monk skill deals the most damage per spirit?

Tags: diablo-iii, diablo-iii-monk

I don't quite know which skills do the most damage (preferably AoE) but have a relatively low spirit cost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the **dps (damage per spirit)** of all the Monk AOE spells, taken from http://us.battle.net/d3/en/class/monk/active/.

Note that I'm only listing AOE skills that hit a bunch of enemies at once (not Seven-Sided Strike or Tempest Rush), only runes that increase damage or lower spirit cost, and not listing spirit generators.

Skills, listed in decreasing dps:

- Lashing Tail Kick: Spinning Flame Kick: 240% weapon damage for 30 spirit = 8 dps
- Lashing Tail Kick: Vulture Claw Kick: 220% weapon damage for 30 spirit = 7.33 dps
- Lashing Tail Kick: 200% weapon damage for 30 spirit = 6.67 dps
- Wave of Light: Pillar of the Ancients: 420% weapon damage for 75 spirit = 5.6 dps
- Wave of Light: Empowered Light: 215% weapon damage for 40 spirit = 5.38 dps
- Wave of Light: Wall of Light: 312% weapon damage for 75 spirit = 4.16 dps
- Wave of Light: Explosive Light: 285% weapon damage for 75 spirit = 3.8 dps
- Cyclone Strike: Eye of the Storm: 100% weapon damage for 30 spirit = 3.33 dps
- Breath of Heaven: Circle of Scorn: 80% weapon damage for 25 spirit = 3.2 dps
- Wave of Light: 215% weapon damage for 75 spirit = 2.87 dps
- Cyclone Strike: 100% weapon damage for 50 spirit = 2 dps

Of course, this is very situational. Some of these spells affect a large area and will make it easy to hit a dozen monsters. Some affect a cone or path and will make it hard to hit more than 2 or 3.

Comment: +1 to this. In my observation, Lashing tail kick with the spinning flame kick rune does considerable damage and can be case multiple times for a low spirit cost.

Comment: Sweeping Wind: Potentially infinite!

Comment: @OrigamiRobot Yeah, a lot of these are hard to compare, for reasons like that. I tried to impose some rules to have the comparisons make sense, but your mileage may vary.

Comment: this should be updated, seven sided strike after 1.04 buff with fulminating strike or sudden assault (for aoe or single target damage) is by far the highest damage per spirit

Comment: @yx. I will try to update it later this week when I have time. If anyone has the data now, go for it!